# Trouble Accessing Ajax POST variable on Codeigniter end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using jquery to make ajax calls. Basically I don't know how to access the data I'm sending to the server with a post request. I don't know what the variable is called or... something. I don't know!

**Ajax functions:**

```
function ajax_client(url, json) {

    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: json,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function gather_records(data, inp_col, fetch_col, limit) {

    var json = JSON.stringify({
        "ids"        : data,
        "inp_col"    : inp_col,
        "fetch_col"  : fetch_col,
        "limit"      : limit
    });

    return ajax_client(base_url+'ajax_port/gather_records', json);
}
```

**Codeigniter Function:**

```
public function gather_records() 
{

    $data      = json_decode($this->input->post('ids'));

    log_message('debug', $data);//null

    return json_encode($data);//null :(
}
```

I'm having no trouble receiving data back from the server here (and accessing with jQuery), my problem is that I can't get the data I'm sending *to* codeigniter. I'm developing on MAMP if that makes any difference.

I've tried other variable names like,

```
$this->input->post('data');
$this->input->post('json');
```

None seem to work.
Thanks very much for any help I can get!

Comment: Did you checked your browser console?Is it sending ajax request at right path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do `JSON.stringify({..`

just pass an object, and everything will be fine. I mean:

```
function ajax_client(url, json) {

    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: json,
        dataType: 'json'
    });
}

function gather_records(data, inp_col, fetch_col, limit) {

    var json = {
        "ids"        : data,
        "inp_col"    : inp_col,
        "fetch_col"  : fetch_col,
        "limit"      : limit
    };

    return ajax_client(base_url+'ajax_port/gather_records', json);
}
```

---

One more thing. You don't need to `json_decode` it in your PHP side. Because default contentType in `jQuery` is `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Change line

```
$data      = json_decode($this->input->post('ids'));
```

to

```
$data      = $this->input->post('ids');
```

But if you really want to send JSON, you can add `contentType`

```
    return $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        data: json,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });
```

`dataType` you have set is "The type of data that you're expecting back from the server." (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: This doesn't change anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Try to look in your Browser console. You will see if you get some errors. More over, you can look at Network tab (I'm not sure which browser are you using) and you will see your request. Try to learn to debug, it's good thing

Comment: This changes the response from null to false.

Comment: So this answer wasn't "accepted"? Any way, glad to hear you found solution and good luck for you